# Directory with same name subdirectory move

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, batch-rename

I got myself stuck and can't seem to find a quick way to fix this.

I have an external HDD with a folder structure like this:

- `\folder1`
- `\folder2`
- `\folder3`

some of these have a subdirectory named the same, like so

- `\folder1`
- `\folder2\folder2`
- `\folder3\folder3`

I would love to use batch, if possible, to basically only look for the same name one directory deep and, if it matches, then move all files from `\folder2\folder2` to `\folder2`.

I have a total of 640 folders to rip through for this fix.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637511/create-subfolder-with-same-name-as-parent) that was the opposite of what I wanted to do. 
Everything I tired on my test structure would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if possible,
I suggest that you backup the entire directory tree,
just in case something goes wrong.  Then, try typing the command

```
for /d %d in (*) do @echo move %d\%d\* %d
```

This should output something like

```
move folder1\folder1\* folder1
move folder2\folder2\* folder2
move folder3\folder3\* folder3
```

If that looks like a plausible sequence of commands, leave out the `echo`:

```
for /d %d in (*) do @move %d\%d\* %d
```

This will give an error message for `folder1`,
since `folder1\folder1` doesn't exist.  It will also give an error message
for any folder where the second-level folder is empty.

If you want to suppress the error messages for the folders where the second-level folder doesn't exist, put the following into a batch file:

```
@echo off
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    if exist %%d\%%d\nul (
        echo move %%d\%%d\* %%d
    ) else (
        echo %%d\%%d doesn't exist.
    )
)
```

or simply

```
@echo off
for /d %%d in (*) do if exist %%d\%%d\nul echo move %%d\%%d\* %%d
```

(Note that you must use `%%` in a batch file
where you use `%` directly at the command prompt.)

Obviously, there's a risk that you will have identically-named files
in a directory and its subdirectory,
e.g., `folder2\shopping.lst` and `folder2\folder2\shopping.lst`. 
In my quick testing in an unimportant directory tree,
it asked whether I wanted to overwrite (i.e., clobber)
the target (upper-level) file. 
As I said, I suggest that you backup your files first, just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. In my test file structure this worked perfectly. I will make a back up of my live data and give this a try but I feel it will work out just fine. Thanks again.